# Using Wireshark on terminial to show mysql byte responses and queries at same time

Tags: mysql, wireshark

Hi I am using the terminal under Linux

I am trying to analyse mysql packets sent in response to some simple queries.

I can see the queries with the command

```
tshark -i any -d tcp.port==3306,mysql -T fields -e mysql.query 'port 3306'
```

and I can also see the responses (numbers not content) sent from mysql using

```
tshark -i any -d tcp.port==3306,mysql  'port 3306'
```

i.e

```
  1 0.000000000 89.200.139.212 -> 127.0.0.1    MySQL 89 Request Query
  2 0.000199026    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    MySQL 79 Response OK
  3 0.000310118 89.200.139.212 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 33170 > mysql [ACK] Seq=22 Ack=12 Win=11256
```

Is there some way I can see the queries sent and see the byte array of the responses sent back from MySQL on the terminal at the same time?
so I can see the which bytes are sent in response to which sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the command

```
tshark -i any -d tcp.port==3306,mysql -T fields -e mysql.query -e mysql.payload 'port 3306'
```